# How to bulkify this trigger m new to salesforce

Tags: triggercontext, before-trigger, trigger

```
trigger CreatingPayments on Payment__c (after insert,after update) {

 list<Test__c> MD=new list<Test__c>(); 

 for(Payment__c op:trigger.new)
    {
        list<Test__c> MD1=[SELECT Id,Name,Order_Product__c,Order__c,Payment__c FROM Test__c where Payment__c =:op.id ];
        list<Orderitem> pd=[SELECT PriceBookEntry.Name,PriceBookEntry.Productcode,AvailableQuantity,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Description,Discount_Amount__c,Discount__c,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,ListPrice,Net_Price__c,OrderId,OrderItemNumber,OriginalOrderItemId,PricebookEntryId,Quantity,SystemModstamp,Total_Net_Price__c,Total_Price__c,UnitPrice FROM OrderItem  where OrderId=:op.OrderId__c];
        system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+pd);
      if(MD1.size()==0)
        {
            for(integer i=0;i<pd.size();i++)
            {
                Test__c om=new Test__c();
                om.Payment__c=op.id;
                om.Order__c=op.OrderId__c;
                om.Order_Product__c=pd[i].Id;
                om.Product_Code__c=pd[i].PriceBookEntry.Productcode;                     
                MD.add(om);
            }
        }

    }
insert MD;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue in your trigger is that you are using 2 SOQL's inside your for loop which is never a best practice. As it may later result in more than 100 queries limitation. You should modify your code by storing the SOQL values in the sets or list and then iterating your loop over it.

You can use the below links to learn more on how to bulkify the trigger.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/

**EDIT : Adding the modified code.**

```
Trigger CreatingPayments on Payment__c(after insert,after update) 
{

List<Test__c> MD = new List<Test__c>(); 
Set<Id> PayId = new Set<Id>(); //Set to save the payment Ids
set<Id> OrdId = new Set<Id>(); //Set to save the related Order Ids of payment

List<Payment__c> Pay  = [Select Id, OrderId__c from Payment__c where id =: Trigger.new];
For(Payment__c P: Pay)
{
    IF(pay.size() != 0)
    {
        PayId.add(P.Id);
        OrdId.add(p.OrderId__c);
    }
}

List<Test__c> MD1 = [SELECT Id FROM Test__c where Payment__c =: PayId ];
List<Orderitem> pd = [SELECT Id,PriceBookEntry.Productcode FROM OrderItem where OrderId=: OrdId];

If(MD1.size()== 0)
{
    For(Payment__c op : Pay)
    {
        For(Integer i=0 ; i < pd.size() ; i++)
        {
            Test__c om = new Test__c();
            om.Payment__c = op.id;
            om.Order__c = op.OrderId__c;
            om.Order_Product__c = pd[i].Id;
            om.Product_Code__c = pd[i].PriceBookEntry.Productcode;                     
            MD.add(om);
        }
    }
}
Insert MD;
}
```

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: Can u help with code

Comment: I have two queries which is taking payment id in query that's why it is in for loop ..

Comment: @Learner : I have added the modified code for you. If you have any issues then let me know. If this solves your question then please mark this question as solved by marking this as best answer so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Rushi's answer is correct, but I would say it in another way: you should always aim to get everything that you MIGHT use with a query at the beginning, or at least outside a for loop. And then, treat the values accordingly in the code.

In your current situation, you shouldn't have too much to change in your code. One thing that I would change, and I think it is considered a good practice, is to change the way you are iterating over that list of OrderItem. You can iterate over it in a simpler way:

```
for (OrderItem oi : pd)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

It is just a suggestion to improve readability, though. There's nothing wrong in using a variable to control the loop.

Comment: If i use for loop how will add payment id in the soql pd

Comment: Do another loop before, getting the Ids in OrderId__c into a list, and in the OrderItem query you can do "OrderId IN :<yourIdList>".